# Calling generic method gives compiler error

Tags: c#, interface, service-locator

I want to decouple some things in my code so that I don't have to include DLLs that are used in the main project also in the sub-project. For this i have created the following method to register services (which uses the MS Common Practices Service Locator):

```
public static void RegisterService<TInterface>(SPSite site) where TInterface : IServiceLocatorRegisterable, new()
        {
            GetServiceLocatorConfig(site).RegisterTypeMapping<IServiceLocatorRegisterable, TInterface>(typeof(TInterface).FullName);
            InvalidateCache();
```

So, as you see I created the Interface "IServiceLocatorRegisterable" so that I'm not bound to a specific interace yet.

In the sub project I have a specific interface I want to register with the service locator, so I added the "IServiceLocatorRegisterable" to the declaration:

```
public interface ISapProcess : IServiceLocatorRegisterable
{ // details omitted.. }
```

And this is the code where I try to register this interface:

```
public static void RegisterSapProcess(SPSite site)
{
    ServiceLocator.RegisterService<ISapProcess>(site);
}
```

But I cannot compile it as I get the follwing compiler error:

> ISapProcess must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
>   constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TInterface' in the
>   generic type or method '....RegisterService(SPSite)'

.. and as I know see it doesn work either when I would try to register the "base interface" directly (which of course wouldn't make any sense, as I want to register and locate the specific interfaces/implemenations):

```
ServiceLocator.RegisterService<IServiceLocatorRegisterable>(site);
```

I have the feeling that I'm missing something important here.

Comment: It's a SharePoint class from microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yes - look at your constraint:

```
where TInterface : IServiceLocatorRegisterable, new()
```

You can't write:

```
ISapProcess x = new ISapProcess();
```

can you? That's what the constraint requires.

You *either* need to ditch the constraint, or change your type argument. (It's not clear what you're trying to do given the code you've provided.)

Comment: Ah, I see. I now get what you mean, let me modify my code. Keep you updated.